# How can I retrieve the variances in the ICC formula in R?

Tags: r, reliability, standard-error

One of the formula to calculate an intra-class correlation coefficient (ICC) is the following:

[image]

I would like to retrieve the value of each component in R in order to calculate the SEM using the following formula

[image]

However, the packages that can be used to calculate an ICC don't provide these values in their output. Here's a dataframe to test that out (4 judges, testing the inter-rater reliability):

```
library(psych)
df<-data.frame("J1"=c(9,6,8,7,10,6),"J2"=c(2,1,4,1,5,2),"J3"=c(5,3,6,2,6,4),"J4"=c(8,2,8,6,9,7))
ICC(df)

#or using irr package
library(irr)
icc(df)
```

The output from neither of these packages is satisfactory. Any advice?

Comment: you can get the variance components from the `lme4` object: `out = ICC(df)  ; lme4::VarCorr(out$summary)`

Comment: ... actually help if i read the help page of ?ICC: use `out$lme`

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error message, though. Anything missing?

Comment: nope. running `library(psych) ; df<-data.frame("J1"=c(9,6,8,7,10,6),"J2"=c(2,1,4,1,5,2),"J3"=c(5,3,6,2,6,4),"J4"=c(8,2,8,6,9,7)) ; out = ICC(df) ; out$lme` gives the variance components

Comment: ... although perhaps you don't have lme4 - it is only [suggested](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/index.html). So try installing `lme4`, and then rerunning

Comment: lme4 is installed. I get "NULL" as a result.

Comment: okay ; sorry I have nothing else to suggest - the code in my earlier comment works as expected for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, when I do `str(out)`I don't see `$lme` in the output.

Comment: what does `packageVersion("psych")`. I'm 1.8.3.3.  (If you look at `?ICC` you should see under `value`, that `lme` is returned if using the lmer option. As the default is `lmer=TRUE` it should be there

Comment: If you still can't get it , then code it your self `library(lme4) ;
m = reshape2::melt(df, variable.name="id") ;m$items = with(m, ave(as.character(id), id, FUN=seq_along)) ;mod <- lmer(value ~ 1 + (1|id) + (1|items), data=m)` - then grab the variance components

Comment: Hey it's working now! I was running an old version of psych. Many thanks, you've made my day :)

Comment: great stuff ... please consider writing it up as an answer.